# Using Shazam to pick up audio over internal soundcard / headphones

Tags: macos, audio, microphone, shazam

I recently discovered [Shazam has an app for mac](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/shazam/id897118787), it seems it works by listening on the built in mic (or any mic presumably).

I wondered if there was a way I could get it to listen to the soundcard instead? I typically listen to radio streams over VLC, through headphones and thought it would be awesome to be able to use Shazam for those unknown tunes.

I found out about the Audio MIDI Setup.app which you can create aggregate devices, I thought maybe I could somehow forward the output into the mic- but I don't really understand it exactly truth be told.

Is there a way I could get this to work?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I believe Shazam does this by default now?

Comment: @cathalog it does? on the mac version? Is there a way to enable this? I doesn't seem to do it for me

Comment: It definitely does. I'm using v1.1.2 (Build 29). The reason I stumbled upon this question, is because I was wondering if anyone could get it working over Bluetooth headphones. I can only seem to get it working with headphones plugged into the headphone jack.

Comment: @cathalog I'm on the same version and it doesn't appear to work for me and there's no options or preferences I can see either. Do your headphones leak sound by any chance, and could be getting picked up by the microphone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this like so:

1. Install Soundflower (from https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/)
2. Option-click the volume icon and change both the input and the output device to "Soundflower (2ch)"
3. Start the Soundflowerbed application that comes with Soundflower, then click its icon in the top right (of a flower) and choose "Built-in Output" from the list under "Soundflower (2ch)"

Now your system audio output (e.g. VLC) is going out on the Soundflower virtual audio cable and your system input (e.g. Shazam) is coming from the Soundflower virtual audio cable, so Shazam can listen to whatever you play on the Mac, but Soundflowerbed lets you also route that virtual audio cable out through the system audio output so you can hear it all the time!

This could have a slightly negative effect on CPU usage and latency, so you might not want to use this set up all the time if you aren't using Shazam - in this case, you just Option-click the volume icon and set the output (and input if required) back to "Built-in". It's really cool to have Shazam IDing tracks as you listen to a DJ mix/radio station, and it's (sometimes) impressively accurate!

Comment: Hey works great! Did you mean option-click though rather than cmd-click? Only issue is the audio routed through soundflower seems to be quite a bit quieter but it's definitely working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah yeah, option-click! I'll edit accordingly, I get confused with all those modifier keys ;)

Regarding the audio volume - you need to bear in mind you now have two volume levels affecting it: the volume level going into the Soundflower virtual audio cable (which you can set when Soundflower 2ch is selected as the output), and the level of your Mac's audio output (which you can set when Audio Output is selected). What I tend to do is put my Audio Output volume higher than I would normally listen to, then have the Soundflower one near 100%, with some room to go a bit louder.

Comment: One other thing I've found is that sometimes the audio crackles a little, but this can be avoided by increasing the buffer size in Soundflowerbed

Comment: Seems like Soundflowerbed is... not available anymore? It wasn't with the installer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Soundflower](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) - freeware internal audio router

Comment: Awesome- I'll give it go (once I'm able to give my mac a restart :P)

Comment: Wish you luck - I've not tried it for the setup you mentioned; in fact I haven't needed it in a while so I'm a bit out of practise with it, hence my rather terse Answer ;) but I used to find it very useful.

Comment: If I select soundflower as the output in VLC then I can no longer hear anything over the headphones. I've tried creating an aggregate device with the built-in output and soundflower but I still can't seem to hear anything over the headphones- maybe I'm not doing it right?

Comment: It's been too long since I used it; I don't even actually have it installed on this machine - I think you need to check system outputs & Soundflower's output itself… I found this - http://www.sylvanadvantage.com/index.php/support/how-tos/65-3rd-party-applications-info/188-how-to-use-sound-flower

Answer (score 1):

It works with soundflower on el capitan again. WoW, installed soundflower version 2.0b2 and be sure to uninstall earlier versions first with the given script in the 2.0b2 installer (available at GitHub). If you set with the alt-click option on the volume icon all (both input and output) to soundflower(2chl). If you have no real audio output anymore you can create e.g. a multi-output device in audio/midi configuration. This will disable audio volume control. Instead I can use soundflowerbed v1.1.6 again with no trouble on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
With Soundflowerbed volume control keeps being in control.

Answer (score -1):

SoundflowerBed is available separately from Soundflower. You can get SoundflowerBed here: https://github.com/mLupine/SoundflowerBed

Answer (score -3):

No, no ,no.

THE EASIEST WAY YOU DO IT - IS THROUGH WINDOWS SOUND settings (go to them and select RECORDING, then **STEREO MIX** and enable it and then right click it (stereo mix) and click **LISTEN** and then **Listen to this device** (aditionally select what device is playing the audio).

Then hit OK and shazam will work (you may have to dissable all other microphones or just set stero mix to default).

You just usually need some soundcard for this (Asus works good) - but in asus drivers you should alway disable FX and GX and use ***Classic*** as effect. Also to generally improve quality on soundcards - just dissable unused playback devices / recording devices (use only those that you use).

Comment: Where do I find windows sound settings on a Mac?